# Mesh array on curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm making a short animation and I would like to fit an array on a curve. But the array isn't as long as the curve.

Here is a picture.
[image: array on curve]

Comment: Oh, I now see that you did everything I said to do in my answer. Try applying the scale on both objects.

Comment: I applied the scale on both of them. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fit curve option in the array modifier.

[image]

When you use this, how ever long the curve is, the array amount will always change to match it. Make sure you apply the scale of both object, or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to match the origins:

- Select the curve. Enter 'Edit Mode', by <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Select the starting vertex (where the arrows point in the direction of the curve)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, 'Cursor to Selected'
- Exit 'Edit Mode', by <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- (While curve selected), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, 'Origin to 3D Cursor'
- Select the array, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, 'Origin to 3D Cursor'
- (While array selected) press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter 'Edit Mode', press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, press <kbd>A</kbd> (once or twice to select everything), 'Selection to Cursor (offset) and exit 'Edit Mode', by <kbd>Tab</kbd>

You could try to play with the 'Deformation Axis' in the Curve modifier as well

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your Array modifier is operating on the Z axis and your Curve modifier is set to deform on the X axis. Can you change your Array modifier to operate on the X axis instead. This is assuming all object rotations have been applied.